# Basic jQuery Slider not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add [Basic jQuery Slider](http://basic-slider.com) to my website. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="slides">
<ul class="bjqs">
<li><a href="somelink"><img src="someimage" width="1200" height="200" title="Test"/></a></li>
<li><a href="somelink"><img src="someimage" width="1200" height="200" title="Test2"/></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#slides').bjqs({
        animtype: 'slide',
        height : 1200,
        width : 200,
        responsive : true
    });
});
</script>
```

Nothing appears! No image, no slider nothing.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/46S6g/

Comment: Did you include the relevant files?

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? Did you include jQuery?

Comment: @j08691 I got no errors. Yes, I included jQuery.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: The proper syntax is `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` (no $).

Comment: @j08691 I fixed it but it is still not working

Comment: Have you tried wrapping animtype, height, width, and responsive in quotations per the example on their website? Check under Activation on their website http://basic-slider.com/

Comment: @theClap I tried but still doesn't work

Comment: Without being able to reproduce in a jsFiddle I doubt there's much we can do to help.

Comment: @j08691 http://jsfiddle.net/46S6g/

Comment: @j08691 It's not working?

Comment: @j08691 That is exactly the problem... If you remove the css look what happens.

Comment: No - in your fiddle you forget to include the link to the slider plugin. That is probably what you did on your site too. TypeError: $(...).bjqs is not a function AND you haven't followed the instructions provided on the slider's site.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/46S6g/2/

It worked fine for me after I included the plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to include the plugin itself.

```
<script src="bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Here's a functioning jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/46S6g/3/

I've linked to the plugin in the External Resources pane in jsFiddle and loaded the latest version of jQuery in the Frameworks & Extensions panel.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Thats what I did and it works, like others said you should check if you really included all files.

http://jsfiddle.net/rVHAx/1/

```
$(function() {
$('#slides').bjqs({
    animtype: 'slide',
    height : 200,
    width : 300,
    responsive : true
});
```